# KConfig mix files

Tags: embedded, kbuild

I'm currently developing some firmware for an ESP32 device. I reached the stage in the development process in which I need to write some stuff in the Kconfig file.

I'm just developing one component and I have my own Kconfig file. But in the "make menuconfig" there is a specific entry(created by one developer of the team) in which I want to add some entries from my kconfig file. Is there anyway to do it?
Is there anyway to add entries from different kconfig files? Some kind of include.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please give some examples, Share your question in detail. Provided details not enough to get the answer as you may expect :(

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710022/adding-new-driver-code-to-linux-source-code> This link might help you to understand Kconfig stuffs

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just mix some KConfig files. Imagine that you have  a different KConfig file for one component and you want to add a menu entry in the principal menu for your whole device and you want an entry for each component(kconfig file of the component).

As simple as that, some kind of include, some kind of way to relate the different kconfig files inside the same project.

Comment: Share me your changes, or give some examples which will help users to understand better and give you samples